# Advice on how to use a for loop to compare columns and input into a vector

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to make a vector of counts comparing a number of columns to one called `truth`. I'm really not sure how this works, so any advice would be helpful because this isn't working for me so far.

```
k=13
for(i in 1:k){
  TPR<- tumor %>% filter(tumor1[,i]==T) %>% filter(tumor1[,i]==truth) %>% tally() 
}
```

For the sake of reproducibility, you can use this code, but it's really embarassing so there's that:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

malig<-c(.49, .36, .58, .56, .61, .66)
benign<-c(.42, .22, .26, .53, .31 ,.41)

tumor<- NULL
tumor$malig<- malig
tumor$benign<- benign
tumor<-tumor %>% as.data.frame()

tumor<- tumor %>% pivot_longer(cols=c(malig,benign), names_to="status") %>% arrange(status)

cutoffs<-c(.2, .25, .3, .35, .37, .4, .45, .5, .55, .57, .6, .65, .7)

tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Twenty = ifelse(value > .2, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Twentyfive = ifelse(value > .25, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Thirty = ifelse(value > .3, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Thirtyfive = ifelse(value > .35, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Thirtyseven = ifelse(value > .37, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Forty = ifelse(value > .4, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Fortyfive = ifelse(value > .45, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Fifty = ifelse(value > .5, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Fiftyfive = ifelse(value > .55, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Fiftyseven = ifelse(value > .57, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Sixty = ifelse(value > .6, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Sixtyfive = ifelse(value > .65, T, F))
tumor<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, Seventy = ifelse(value > .7, T, F))

tumor1<- tumor %>% mutate(tumor, truth=ifelse(status=="malig", T, F))
tumor1<- tumor1 %>% select(-value,-status)
k=13
for(i in 1:k){
  TPR<- tumor1 %>% filter(tumor1[,i]==T) %>% filter(tumor1[,i]==truth) %>% tally()
  
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you make the example reproducible? This helps posters know your expected results.

Comment: I appreciate the addition of the example. And what is the expected output?

Comment: A vector of the number of observations in common between the `truth` column and all others in the `tumor1` dataframe

Comment: And could you include that in code? I feel as though the example code may have errors. See what your ```tumor1``` returns.

Comment: My apologies. It should work like a dream now up until the for loop

Comment: Ok. It works like a dream. And what is the expected output? Meaning, ```TPR = c(3, 2, 1)``` where you include the correct output for TPR.

Comment: TPR = c(*thirteen numbers that represent the number of instances where the value in  columns 1-13 is equal to the corresponding value in `truth` column)   Ideally something like `TPR=c(6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this :

```
library(dplyr)

tumor1 %>% summarise(across(Twenty:Seventy, ~sum(. & truth)))
```

which in base R would be :

```
colSums(tumor1[-ncol(tumor1)] & tumor1$truth)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach:

```r
library(data.table)

lu_cutoffs = data.table(cutoffs = c(.2, .25, .3, .35, .37, .4, .45, .5, .55, .57, .6, .65, .7))

dt = setDT(stack(list(malig = malig,benign = benign)))
dt[, ind := as.character(ind)]

dt[ind == 'malig'
   ][lu_cutoffs,
   on = .(values > cutoffs),
   .N,
   by = .EACHI]

#    values     N
#     <num> <int>
# 1:   0.20     6
# 2:   0.25     6
# 3:   0.30     6
# 4:   0.35     6
# 5:   0.37     5
# 6:   0.40     5
# 7:   0.45     5
# 8:   0.50     4
# 9:   0.55     4
#10:   0.57     3
#11:   0.60     2
#12:   0.65     1
#13:   0.70     0
```

Basically, we first simplify the `tidyr::pivot_longer` with the `stack` line. Then, we filter to `malig` only and then do a non-equi join to a lookup of cutoffs.

This is a largely equivalent `dplyr` approach, although it looses the value 0.70.

```r
tib = as_tibble(stack(list(malig = malig,benign = benign)))

tib %>%
  crossing(cutoffs)%>%
  filter(values > cutoffs,
         ind == "malig")%>%
  count(cutoffs) 

# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#    cutoffs     n
#      <dbl> <int>
#  1   0.2       6
#  2   0.25      6
#  3   0.3       6
#  4   0.35      6
#  5   0.37      5
#  6   0.4       5
#  7   0.45      5
#  8   0.5       4
#  9   0.55      4
# 10   0.570     3
# 11   0.6       2
# 12   0.65      1
```